# Why does sinatra nginx recipe recommend only 1 worker?

Tags: nginx, sinatra

Here's a snippet from the recommended nginx config file from the [sinatra website's recipe for hosting sinatra with nginx and unicorn](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/deployment/nginx_proxied_to_unicorn).  Note two things that differ from a typical nginx setup:

1. only 1 worker process is specified
2. accept_mutex, typically on by default, is turned off

What is the reason for having only 1 worker?  What would happen if we specified more?

Is `accept_mutex off` purely a consequence of having only 1 worker, or is there another reason for that?

```
# this sets the user nginx will run as, 
#and the number of worker processes
user nobody nogroup;
worker_processes  1;

# setup where nginx will log errors to 
# and where the nginx process id resides
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
  # set to on if you have more than 1 worker_processes 
  accept_mutex off;
}
```

Comment: It probably doesn't have anything to do with the relationship between the two, just the fact that whoever wrote the tutorial was using a single processor machine (usually you assign one worker process per core with Nginx).

Comment: ah, that makes sense.  and turning the mutex off then follows from having only 1 worker... if you want to change your comment to an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably doesn't have anything to do with the relationship between the two, just the fact that whoever wrote the tutorial was using a single processor machine (usually you assign one worker process per core with Nginx).